# Can I dump a Symfony form's validation schema to JSON?

Tags: validation, symfony, schema, symfony-forms

I'm considering setting up some proof-of-concept tool that could grab metadata from a Symfony2 `FormType` instance in order to dump a validation schema as JSON, something like the following:

```
[
    {
        name: 'someFieldName',
        value: '',
        email: true
    },
    {
        name: 'yetAnotherFieldName',
        value: 'I have a default value',
        required: true
    }
]
```

The aim obviously is to use it in front-end JS code (let's say React), to be able to set up the same validation constraints, as much as possible (`required` and the likes).

However, Symfony is well-architectured and its Form component knows nothing about validation. Considering only the nominal case of a simple form to begin with, how would one go about doing it? How to map back the form to the validatable objects/entities it references?

Answer (score 3):

Using the symfony validator you can get the metadata for a given class:

```
$this->get('validator')->getMetadataFor(Foo::class);
```

It returns a `ClassMetadata` instance. If the passed value is an entity, you will have the `members` and `properties` properties returned which then contain a `constraints` property with the classes being used.

Final step is to serialize that in JSON.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, my main concern rather is how to get to that point starting with a `FormType` instance. Thanks though!